# Realm Error: Failed to read ObjectSchema: JS value must be of type 'object', got

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I am trying to add a to in my local storage using realm when I click the add button, here is my code as I've I was following the documentation and tried to tweak it my own way

```
  const addToDo = () => {
    Realm.open({
      schema: [
        'Todo',
        {
          properties: {
            name: 'string',
          },
        },
      ],
    })
      .then((realm) => {
        realm.write(() => {
          realm.create('Todo', {name: todo});
          // realm.close();
        });
        setData({realm});
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```